# How to show data of current logged user in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables. First is user which has an 'email' as a username. Second is customer which alos has email column. And third table is shipments. The shipment has relationship with customer table. User can login with email id which is present in User and Customer table. When user is logged in with their email I wamt to show shipments related to respective user, filterdered by email address of current logged in user. Please guide be. below is my index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="page-titles">
  <h2> Vishal {{ $pageTitle }} <small> {{ $pageNote }} </small></h2>
  <h4></h4>
</div>

<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="toolbar-nav" >   
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-4">
                    <div class="input-group ">
                          
                          <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm onsearch" data-target="{{ url($pageModule) }}" aria-label="..." placeholder=" Type And Hit Enter ">
                        </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-md-8 col-8  text-right">    
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        @if($access['is_add'] ==1)
                        <a href="{{ url('shipments/create?return='.$return) }}" class="btn  btn-sm btn-primary"  
                            title="{{ __('core.btn_create') }}"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> {{ __('core.btn_create') }}</a>
                        @endif
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-bars"></i> Bulk Action </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            @if($access['is_remove'] ==1)
                                 <li class="nav-item"><a href="javascript://ajax"  onclick="SximoDelete();" class="nav-link tips" title="{{ __('core.btn_remove') }}">
                                Remove Selected </a></li>
                            @endif 
                            @if($access['is_add'] ==1)
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="javascript://ajax" class=" copy nav-link " title="Copy" > Copy selected</a></li>
                                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url($pageModule .'/import?return='.$return) }}" onclick="SximoModal(this.href, 'Import CSV'); return false;" class="nav-link "> Import CSV</a></li>

                                
                            @endif
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            @if($access['is_excel'] ==1)
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url( $pageModule .'/export?do=excel&return='.$return) }}" class="nav-link "> Export Excel </a></li>    
                            @endif
                            @if($access['is_csv'] ==1)
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url( $pageModule .'/export?do=csv&return='.$return) }}" class="nav-link "> Export CSV </a></li>    
                            @endif
                            @if($access['is_pdf'] ==1)
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url( $pageModule .'/export?do=pdf&return='.$return) }}" class="nav-link "> Export PDF </a></li>    
                            @endif
                            @if($access['is_print'] ==1)
                                <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url( $pageModule .'/export?do=print&return='.$return) }}" class="nav-link "> Print Document </a></li>  
                            @endif
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url($pageModule) }}"  class="nav-link "> Clear Search </a></li>
                                
                            
                              
                            </ul>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                </div>
                   
            </div>  

        </div>  

            <!-- Table Grid -->
            
            {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'shipments?'.$return, 'class'=>'form-horizontal m-t' ,'id' =>'SximoTable' )) !!}
            <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table  table-hover table-striped  " id="{{ $pageModule }}Table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width: 3% !important;" class="number"> No </th>
                        <th  style="width: 3% !important;"> 
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkall filled-in" id="checked-all"  />
                            <label for="checked-all"></label>
                        </th>
                        
                        
                        @foreach ($tableGrid as $t)
                            @if($t['view'] =='1')               
                                <?php $limited = isset($t['limited']) ? $t['limited'] :''; 
                                if(SiteHelpers::filterColumn($limited ))
                                {
                                    $addClass='class="tbl-sorting" ';
                                    if($insort ==$t['field'])
                                    {
                                        $dir_order = ($inorder =='desc' ? 'sort-desc' : 'sort-asc'); 
                                        $addClass='class="tbl-sorting '.$dir_order.'" ';
                                    }
                                    echo '<th align="'.$t['align'].'" '.$addClass.' width="'.$t['width'].'">'.\SiteHelpers::activeLang($t['label'],(isset($t['language'])? $t['language'] : array())).'</th>';              
                                } 
                                ?>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                        <th  style="width: 10% !important;">{{ __('core.btn_action') }}</th>
                        
                      </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>                             
                    @foreach ($rowData as $row)
                        <tr>
                            <td class="thead"> {{ ++$i }} </td>
                            <td class="tcheckbox">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="ids filled-in" name="ids[]" value="{{ $row->id }}" id="val-{{ $row->id }}" /> 
                                <label for="val-{{ $row->id }}"></label>
                            </td>
                                                                                    
                         @foreach ($tableGrid as $field)
                             @if($field['view'] =='1')
                                <?php $limited = isset($field['limited']) ? $field['limited'] :''; ?>
                                @if(SiteHelpers::filterColumn($limited ))
                                 <?php $addClass= ($insort ==$field['field'] ? 'class="tbl-sorting-active" ' : ''); ?>
                                 <td align="{{ $field['align'] }}" width=" {{ $field['width'] }}"  {!! $addClass !!} >                   
                                    {!! SiteHelpers::formatRows($row->{$field['field']},$field ,$row ) !!}                       
                                 </td>
                                @endif  
                             @endif                  
                         @endforeach    
                         <td>

                                <div class="dropdown">
                                  <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>  </button>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    @if($access['is_detail'] ==1)
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="{{ url('shipments/'.$row->id.'?return='.$return)}}" class="nav-link tips" title="{{ __('core.btn_view') }}"> {{ __('core.btn_view') }} </a></li>
                                    @endif
                                    @if($access['is_edit'] ==1)
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a  href="{{ url('shipments/'.$row->id.'/edit?return='.$return) }}" class="nav-link  tips" title="{{ __('core.btn_edit') }}"> {{ __('core.btn_edit') }} </a></li>
                                    @endif
                                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                    @if($access['is_remove'] ==1)
                                        <li class="nav-item"><a href="javascript://ajax"  onclick="SximoDelete();" class="nav-link  tips" title="{{ __('core.btn_remove') }}">
                                        Remove Selected </a></li>
                                    @endif 
                                  </ul>
                                </div>

                            </td>        
                        </tr>
                        
                    @endforeach
                      
                </tbody>
              
            </table>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="action_task" value="" />
            
            {!! Form::close() !!}
            
            
            <!-- End Table Grid -->

        </div>
        @include('footer')
    </div>      
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.copy').click(function() {
        var total = $('input[class="ids"]:checkbox:checked').length;
        if(confirm('are u sure Copy selected rows ?'))
        {
            $('input[name="action_task"]').val('copy');
            $('#SximoTable').submit();// do the rest here   
        }
    })  
    
}); 
</script>   
    
@stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to display shipments of a logged-in user? Then at this point, I'm expecting that you have already defined the Eloquent Relationships as methods on your Eloquent User and Shipment model classes and actually able to save the data.

In your **Controller**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

public function index()
{
  $user = Auth::user()->load('shipments');
  return view('sample.index', ['user' => $user]);
}
```

With the **Auth::user()** it checks if the current user is authenticated (returns true if the user is logged-in) via the **Auth** facade. Since the User model has already been retrieved, you can use **Lazy Eager Loading** with the *load()* to load the Shipment model.

And in your **blade**, you can display user's info and iterate over the shipment collection like so:

```
@foreach ($user->shipments as $shipment)
 <p>{{ $shipment->field }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: cn u connect on vishal.7003[at]gmail.com